Restart Desktop and Taskbar (explorer.exe) with PowerShell
Using PowerShell and executables to install programs, one of the programs will make the desktop go black and make the taskbar disappear. To get this back, user needs to go to Task Manager and Run a New Task (explorer.exe).
What PowerShell commands can I use to get explorer.exe to launch/restart after a software install, so the user doesn't have to complete these manual steps?

I believe simply running "explorer" or "explorer.exe" will start Explorer if it had stopped/failed.

In most versions of Windows, Explorer.exe should start up by itself! If not, try to kill the process, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66497807/how-do-i-kill-a-processes-running-a-given-executable, and then simply run Explorer.exe in the script, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.4

The explorer process is run on the interactive account so assuming the same context in the install script is the interactive user session, then explorer.exe should suffice. If running the installer as SYSTEM or some other elevated process hoses the explorer session up on the account that is interactively signed in, you might have to explore a different solution such as running explorer.exe as the interactive user that is signed on—you can do this with task scheduler. I second the option to kill explorer.exe instances first then start in case it is hosed while running, kill it, then a new one.

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle Thanks. Yes, was running the installer as SYSTEM. Also discovered that there was a known bug with the version of the program we were installing that was patched, so we've since updated beyond that version.

Most program installers can be run in PowerShell.
My idea is for you to type out something like this, (installer is install.exe in this case.)
PS C:> install.exe ; explorer.exe
The ';' tells PowerShell to execute the next command after the first, (similar to && in Linux.).
